# Use jQuery to post a list to a Struts2 action

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm trying to use jQuery to load the values from a select box (with the "multiple" attribute) and post it to a Struts2 action containing a List variable. My problem is that the java variable never gets populated.

---

Here's what I would like to do (but doesn't work):

Javascript:

```
var params = {
    searchField: $("#multiSelectBox").val(),
};
$.post("myAction", params, successFunction);
```

Java:

```
List<String> searchField;
//Getter & setter for my field here.
//I also tried a "String[] searchField", but that didn't work either.
```

When jQuery posts the data, it looks like this:

```
searchField[]: value1
searchField[]: value2
searchField[]: value3
```

Unfortunately the searchField java variable in my struts2 action doesn't receive this data.

---

I was able to get it working by manually specifying an index for each item to submit. So the javascript looks like this:

```
var params = { };
$($("#multiSelectBox").val()).each(function(i, item) {
    params["searchField[" + i + "]"] = item;
});
$.post("myAction", params, successFunction);
```

---

Is there any way to get around having to loop and manually specify an index number? It seems like the struts2 params interceptor should be able to handle a simple list of Strings in the standard jQuery post format. My workaround with manual index numbers seems really cumbersome -- especially since my real code is submitting several lists, not just one "searchField" list.

Comment: Remove empty brackets `[]` from `searchField[]`.